# Defining color codes in rxvt-unicode

Tags: colors, urxvt, rxvt

Using some of `node.js` tools like `mocha` in my `urxvt` terminal, I have some problems with coloured output. Some of the text that are using colour code 90 as you can see [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/blob/master/mocha.js#L1965) will be disappeared in terminal.

`tput colors` output is:
256

And using this command:

```
(x=`tput op` y=`printf %76s`;for i in {0..256};do o=00$i;echo -e ${o:${#o}-3:3} `tput setaf $i;tput setab $i`${y// /=}(x=`tput op` y=`printf %76s`;for i in {0..256};do o=00$i;echo -e ${o:${#o}-3:3} `tput setaf $i;tput setab $i`${y// /=}$x;done)$x;done)
```

It seems I have all available colours.

But when I try to echo something like this:

```
echo '\e[0;90m shahin \e[m '
```

There will be a just an empty line printed! 
Is there anyway to define this colour code manually?

Thank you all!

Update:
I think some images will describe the situation much better. Here is an image of echo command in `finalterm` terminal:

[image]

And here I put the result from `urxvt`:

[image]

And here is the result of [this](https://code.google.com/p/joeldotfiles/source/browse/trunk/256colors2.pl) `perl` script that is running on the same `urxvt`:

[image]

Comment: You do mean `echo -e` in your second sample I think?

Comment: There is no differences in the result. I tried -e and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not that the color is not visible,
it is just the same as the terminal background, dark gray for example.

The there is a color that is essentially transparent, showing the terminal default color underneath. But it is not shure this color is in use - it may be just that the "black" color used for background is actually the same dark gray as you use for foreground.

If possible, open a teminal that allows to experiment with colors settings easily with a gui, like `konsole` or `gnome-terminal`, and clearly shows what you can change. Or just experiment in `rxvt-unicode` if it is suitable.

I think you will at least have some clue what is wrong, if not a solution.

If it's not solved then, present your new information here, and let's work the details out.

---

Sidenote:

I did not get your long command to work by copy and paste, but it may be similar to
`colortest-256`

from the package `colortest` on Ubuntu etc.

Try `colortest-16` too, it may help to explain your problem.
If not, post a screenshot!

Comment: I added some images to the question. There is also an example of another terminal emulator that shows the colour without problem. The little script you mentioned I found somewhere on the internet that I can't find the source now. But there is an example of a perl script that I added a image of the result up there too.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong escape sequence.

It's close (begins with <kbd>escape</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>, ends with <kbd>m</kbd>), but the wrong parameters.

There are at least three SGR (select graphic rendition) escape sequences which are used to print colors in xterm and similar terminals:

- ANSI (colors 0-7), which use parameters 30-37 (foreground) and 40-47 (background)
- aixterm (colors 8-15), which use parameters 90-97 (foreground) and 100-107 (background)
- 256colors (colors 0-255), which use codes `38;5;`*parameter* (foreground) and `48;5;`*parameter* (background)

So you've selected the aixterm foreground color 8.  By convention, those are shown as brighter versions of colors 0-7.  ANSI color 0 is **black**.  Bright black is... depending on the terminal, it could be gray.  It could be just black.

Perhaps you meant something like this:

```
echo '\e[0;38;5;90m shahin \e[m '
```

although this is portable:

```
printf '\033[0;38;5;90m shahin \033[m \n'
```

Further reading:

- [Can I set a color by its number?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#color_by_number)